# How to make spacing this code

Tags: php, spacing

Simple and newbie question about spacing, how to make spacing before $tag ?

```
$key[rand(0, count($ey)-1)] . $tag
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add a space and concatenate the rest:

```
$key[rand(0, count($ey)-1)] . ' ' . $tag
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the space and concatenate the tag. Like said in the previous answer.

```
$key[rand(0, count($ey) - 1)] . ' ' . $tag;
```

You can also use double quotes like this. In `$x` will be stored the same value as in the example before. This is useful when you want to add many variables together.

```
$myKeyValue = $key[rand(0, count($ey) - 1)];
$x = "$myKeyValue $tag";
```

And the space there is not trimmed, so you can make the space longer if you want.

```
$key[rand(0, count($ey) - 1)] . '     ' . $tag;
```